# Reactjs How can I check a state constant to determine if it has been initialised? (to avoid an error if it has not)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

In my reactJS app I want to create a once-only process until the first render.  I thought to set a state constant to a value - knowing that the value will not be available until after the first render cycle.  But how can I check the state constant to determine if it is has been initialised in the first render?

There are some examples in older ReactJS code (which I have never used and don't understand) but nothing that I can find in contemporary reactJS code.

In the older code (before hooks) the test included  && this.State or something similar.

The reason I need to do this is that I will call a pageRefresh when a navbar tile is clicked in order to ensure that an export occurs (which it will not otherwise).

I store the required page name from the HandleClick function in a cookie but that cookie must be initialised at the start of the code.  A refresh will re-initialise it and I will lose the clicked page name.  But If I can ensure that the initialisation only happens on the first cycle, then I can prevent this and the correct page will be exported when the page is refreshed.

In the very first cycle I initialise the cookies.  Thereafter, the state constant will be available and the initialisation will not occur.

Comment: Show us some code examples, desired behaviour, some context, its hard to understand your question...

Comment: Generally, anything you want to do in the first cycle only you do with `useEffect(()=>{...code...},[])` (note the empty `[]` dependencies array).

Comment: Cool!  I have used useEffect  elsewhere.  Does reactJS just ignore this code after an export/render ?

In this case, there will be a pageRefresh - It runs the code again from the start so I suspect it will re-run the useEffect code as well...  Worth a try though...  :-)

Comment: `useEffect` runs after the first render.

Comment: Ah, ok.  Thanks for this.  I will have a look at this today and see if it will solve my problem...

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways (that I found) to check whether or not a state constant has been initialised:

a)  if(!myConstant) {
... code to run if myConstant IS NOT initialised
}

b) if (myConstant!=null) {
... code to run if myConstant IS initialised
}